# How can i sort an ArrayBlockingQueue in java?

Tags: java

public class Cars implements Comparable{

```
private String company, model;
private int price;


public Cars(String company, String model, int price){
    this.company=company;
    this.model=model;
    this.price=price;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + price;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Cars other = (Cars) obj;
    if (price != other.price)
        return false;
    return true;
}

public String toString(){
    return String.format("Comapany: %s, Model: %s, Price: %d", this.company, this.model, this.price);
}

public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}


public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}


public String getModel() {
    return model;
}


public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}


public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}


public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public int compareTo(Object obj) {


    return this.price-((Cars)obj).price;
}
```

}

public class BlockingQueueExample {

```
BlockingQueue<Cars> queue;
Random random=new Random();
private boolean running=false;

public BlockingQueueExample(BlockingQueue<Cars> queue){
    this.queue=queue;
    running=true;
}

public void producer() throws InterruptedException{

    while(running){
        int add_car=random.nextInt(5);
        Cars value=null;
        switch(add_car){
        case 0:value=new Cars("BMV", "q7", 4000);break;
        case 1:value=new Cars("Renault","KWID", 2000);break;
        case 2:value=new Cars("Porche","Cayenee", 3000);break;
        case 3:value=new Cars("Skoda", "Rapid", 2500);break;
        case 4:value=new Cars("Volkswagen", "Ameo", 3500);break;
        }

        queue.put(value);
        System.out.println("PRODUCER "+ value);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public void consumer() throws InterruptedException{

    while(running){
        Thread.sleep(500);
        if(random.nextInt(5)==0){
            Cars value=queue.take();
            //Collections.sort((List<Cars>) queue);
            System.out.println("CONSUMER Taken value: "+value +", Queue size: "+queue.size()+"\n"+queue);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

public void stop(){
    running=false;
    // method to sort queue
    System.out.println("Sorted queue:"+"\n"+queue);
}
```

}

I tried Arrays.sort(queue.toArray()), Collections.sort(queue), doesn;t wok ; It's for a presentation for tomorrow.... someone pls welp

Comment: First of all, there is no need for the kind of language in your title.  Second of all, we don't know what "welp" means.  Third of all, `ArrayBlockingQueue`s are FIFO structures, and are not meant to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously sorting an `ArrayBlockingQueue` wouldn't work, as it would go against its FIFO design.  If you want a sorted `Queue`, then you should utilize a `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: tried that too(BlockingQueue queue=new PriorityBlockingQueue....), didn;t sorted anything...

Comment: @AndreiBratu Have you defined its generic type to use your `Cars` class?  `BlockingQueue<Cars> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();`

Comment: ye, i just changed from Array to Priority,.... but here is what i should do: so my Cars class should implement hashcode, equals and compareTo to be able for sorting , and in the queue class i should use an PriorityBlockingQueue<Cars> and use Collections.sort or Arrays.sort and then it's done?

Comment: @AndreiBratu The `PriorityBlockingQueue` sorts elements automatically when they are added to the collection; you do not need to use `Arrays#sort` or `Collections#sort`.  You also need to make sure that your `Cars` class implements `Comparable<Cars>`, and that you have the `@Override` annotation on your `Cars#compareTo` method.

Comment: @AndreiBratu You're welcome, and remember that you can upvote/accept any answers that help you!

Comment: So **PriorityBlockingQueue<> with some Comparator<>**  from AndreiBratu is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort the `BlockingQueue`, but you can sort an array of the elements.

You almost had it right with your `Arrays.sort(queue.toArray())` attempt. You just need to remember the array and print it, not the unsorted queue.

```
Cars[] arr = queue.toArray(new Cars[queue.size()]);
Arrays.sort(arr);
System.out.println("Sorted elements:\n" + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

*Unrelated*

You should not use the *raw* generic `Comparable`. Change that to `Comparable<Cars>`.

Also, subtracting integer values to produce `compare()` value is error prone (numeric overflow). Use `Integer.compare()` instead.

```
public class Cars implements Comparable<Cars> {

    // lots of code

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cars other) {
        return Integer.compare(this.price, other.price);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tips; I didn;t wanted to use an array of cars but BlockingQueue because it's a dat structure from concurrent package and I needed it for an example at threads for my presentation :D

Comment: If you don't want the FIFO nature of the [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), you should use the ordered nature of the [`PriorityBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html), but note that it's only ordered for *retrieving* elements, not for *iterating* them: *The `Iterator` provided is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the `PriorityBlockingQueue` in any particular order.*

Comment: ... *If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())` **(see this answer)**. Also, method `drainTo` can be used to remove some or all elements in priority order and place them in another collection.*